# What are the actual requirements for "Playing the Objective"?

Tags: achievements, star-wars-battlefront-2015

I recently started playing blast for the trophy/achievement "Playing the Objective" that states "Have the most kills in a match of Blast".

I have [video evidence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxj0Cod0ePI) of a score screen with confirmation, after the score screen, that I had the most kills in a match of Blast. I did not receive the trophy.

[Recent patch notes say that the previous bug has been fixed](http://starwars.ea.com/starwars/battlefront/forums/discussion/25232/star-wars-battlefront-january-update-ps4-pc-x1), which leads me to believe that this is not a bug. There are hidden requirements. What are they?

> Users with the most kills will now not be prevented from get the
>   Trophy / Achievement ”Playing the objective” in Blast

Comment: If you downvote, please comment why

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your second link is just the text of the quotation, instead of a URL.

Comment: @murgatroid99 whoa thanks! edited, should work now

Comment: Your video is not dated. Are you certain the patch was already deployed? Did you play the whole game from start to finish? Did you get any kills with powerups, like infantry turrets? Just some ideas.

Comment: @DCShannon I asked the question about an hour after uploading the video, and I uploaded the video right as it happened. Infantry turret kills would not count as kills?

Comment: @GarrettJ I don't know, just a guess. If I knew I would post an answer. Did you get some kills like that?

Comment: I know that killing AI (bots) does not count in the total kill count. I don't play a lot of Blast, so I'm not too familiar with the mechanics, but I know in other game modes, the game differentiates between Kills (players) and "AI Kills" (bots).

Comment: @TimS. there are no bots in Blast. Also, I don't believe I had any turret kills. This problem is widely reported, I wonder why people continue to downvote.

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks for the info. No idea for the reasons of downvotes either.

Comment: Regarding the tags: Achievements are not console exclusive, the PC version has the same ones in Origin, so I rolled back the edit.

Answer (score 1):

The achievement would appear to be either bugged or improperly explained, currently the only way to achieve this is to get the most kills in a blast match that runs out of time